# How to make this table responsive

Tags: html, css, html-table, margin, responsive

Can someone help me make this table responsive:

http://footkick.16mb.com

```
<table style="margin: 0px 350px auto;">
    <tr>
        <th style=" background: rgb(25, 97, 208);"><iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i5e8kea0/n136/tluk/fn13/fs24/fc009/ftb/bo3/pa10/tt0/ta1" frameborder="0" width="549" height="50"></iframe></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="color: #fff4f4;background: #dc2121;">
            Site still in Progress!
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: A table with two cells in it, both of which are heading cells, should not be a table in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great article on responsive tables, in summary, you can overwrite the display property for mobile to be display block or inline etc

[Responsive Data Tables](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/)